# Connection to local SQL Server 2012 can be established from SSMS 2008 but not from SSMS 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have two local SQL Server instances running on my local machine. The first is SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition (named MSSQLSERVER) and the 2nd is SQL Server 2012 Business Intelligence Edition.

My problem is with SSMS 2012 which can connect to distant servers but not the local 2012 instance; I can however connect to this instance from SSMS 2008.

The error message I get when trying to login is

> Login Failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows Authentication. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18452)

I must point out that I don't have the necessary privileges to access SQL Server Configuration Manager (blocked by group policy).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try connecting using SQL auth instead of Windows auth?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I did try that but it didn't work.

Comment: And did you get a different error message?

Comment: @IbrahimMezouar Have you solved the issue? I'm afraid that if you don't respond to the questions in the comments, the question will be closed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed the last comment. I have not solved the issue yet.

Comment: @AaronBertrand the error message I get is that the login failed for user sa.

Comment: Ok, so might I suggest you try to login with `sa` and use the right password?

Comment: I am using the right password, but I'm still getting the same error.
Any ideas about my original problem (Windows authentication)?

Comment: What's the instance name for SQL 2012?  Plus did you try going the other way - connecting to the 2008 instance using SSMS 2012?

Answer (score -1):

I saw an item on Pinal Dave's blog recently that *may* answer your question.  He suggests adding the line 
`127.0.0.1 localhost`
to your hosts file

The full article can be found [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/09/06/sql-server-fix-error-cannot-connect-to-login-failed-the-login-is-from-an-untrusted-domain-and-cannot-be-used-with-windows-authentication-microsoft-sql-server-error-18452/)

I do note, however, the situation he refers to is a machine that is not part of a domain - if your machine is, then this may not solve it

Comment: Also this will only help if you are accessing the instance using the explicit name `LOCALHOST\instance name`.

Comment: I am not sure I buy Pinal Dave's explanation. If he was trying to access the IP address 127.0.0.1, adding that entry to the hosts file does nothing - the hosts file is used to resolve names to IP addresses, not the other way around.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. but if the problem really lies within the hosts file, how come SSMS 2008 can connect to both instances? (2008 and 2012)
I reiterate, I'm having this issue only with SSMS 2012.